# Second time connecting to an Excel file through an OleDbConnection I get: AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory"

Tags: c#, .net, excel, oledb

I have seen the other posts that are similar but none have helped me solve my issue.

The first time that I Open the connection there is no issue, that connection is then used to get information from the file, and afterwards closes the file. Manytimes the user will want to repeat this action and the second time it blows up with the exception from the title.

Here is the code that calls it:

```
 public virtual void Open()
        {
            CheckConnection();
            Connection.Close();
            Connection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
            Connection.Open();
        }
```

where `Connection` is of type `OleDbConnection` .

Here is the pertinent part of the stack trace:

```
at System.Data.OleDb.DataSourceWrapper.InitializeAndCreateSession(OleDbConnectionString constr, SessionWrapper& sessionWrapper)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
```

And finally here is the code where I close the connection the first time.

```
Connection.Close();
Connection.Dispose();
OleDbConnection.ReleaseObjectPool();
GC.Collect();
```

Note that I am following the steps from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.releaseobjectpool(v=vs.110).aspx :

Close. Dispose. ReleasePool. Call GC().

and I am still getting

```
System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'
```

I suspect that it is not letting go of the file connection but I suppose it could be something else.

Edit: This is also the connection string that I am using currently (although I have tried many):

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source='C:\Users\Jacob\Documents\book1.xlsx';OLE DB Services=-2;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0';
```

Also here is what I just wrote in a comment: Hmm..if I set a breakpoint before the second time that the connection is opened, I can go into the file explorer and open the file manually, which I would not think I would be able to do if the oledbconnection had control of the file

Comment: Don't know if it would help but you can try adding a call to [GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.waitforpendingfinalizers(v=vs.110).aspx) maybe the `ReleaseObjectPool` has a finalizer that is yet to be run.

Comment: Off topic: why check connection before closing and not capturing errors on close?

Comment: Check connection just checks if the connection object exists and throws an exception if it does not. The close I think is there just as a precaution (I did not write those lines of code)

Comment: @pstrjds that didn't work, but it was worth a shot

Comment: Hmm..if I set a breakpoint before the second time that the connection is opened, I can go into the file explorer and open the file manually, which I would not think I would be able to do if the oledbconnection had control of the file

Comment: Set OLE DB services=-1 or keep the connections open: stackoverflow.com/a/47145747/495455